# DAO functions that populate variables into the SQL query through string concat, rather than using var args and named queries

Tags: java, arguments, dao

I have DAO functions that populate variables into the SQL query through string concat, rather than using var args and named queries. This causes potential SQL injection vulnerabilities as well as HBM query issues such as date formatting, date timezone issues, etc.

I will post a code below which I need to convert to use varargs.I have tons of changes to do like this,but if someone can guide me how to do this I can try to fix the rest.Thanks.

```
public Bidstage findBidstageByName(int companyId, String bidStageName) {
        StringBuffer qbe = new StringBuffer();
        qbe.append("select b from Bidstage b where b.deleted=0 and b.company.idCompany="+companyId+" and b.name='"+bidStageName+"'");
        return (Bidstage) super.findUniqueByQuery(qbe.toString());
    }
```

I need to use varagrs for the above method.

This is how findUniqueByQuery() is

```
protected T findUniqueByQuery(String qbe) throws InfrastructureException { 
Collection<T> c = list(qbe); 
return c.size() > 0 ? c.iterator().next(): null; }
```

This is my list and it looks like its using varargs.I have a scratch project and am trying to learn some coding practise.Is this mean it is using the varagars.

```
protected Collection<T> list(String qbe, Object... parameterMap) throws InfrastructureException { 
return this.findByQuery(qbe, parameterMap); }
```

This is my findByQuery

```
public Collection<T> findByQuery(String qbe, Object... parameterMap) throws InfrastructureException {
        return (Collection<T>) anonymousFindByQuery(qbe, parameterMap);
    }
```

And anonymousFindByQuery

```
public Collection<?> anonymousFindByQuery(String qbe, Object ...parameterMap) 
            throws InfrastructureException{
        getSession();
        try {
            Query q = createQuery(qbe, parameterMap);
            return q.list();
        } //end try
        catch (HibernateException ex) {
            WLog.DAOLogger.error("HibernateException", ex);
            throw new InfrastructureException(ex);
        } //end
    }
```

This one createQuery

```
protected Query createQuery(String qbe, Object... parameterMap) throws InfrastructureException {
        Session session = getSession();
        Query q = session.createQuery(qbe);

        String formattedQuery = String.format("%s ", qbe);

        for (int i = 0; i < parameterMap.length; i = i + 2) {

            //Put the data in easy to use forms.
            Object key = parameterMap[i];
            Object value = parameterMap[i + 1];
            String formattedKey = String.format(":%s ", key);

            if(value == null || formattedQuery.indexOf(formattedKey) == -1){
                continue;
            }

            if(value instanceof ArrayList){
                q.setParameterList(key.toString(), (Collection<?>)value);
            }
            else{
                q.setParameter(key.toString(), value);
            }
        }
        return q;
    }
```

Comment: What does the `findUniqueByQuery()` method look like? They should provide a version that accepts parameters and for example uses `PreparedStatement` to fill them in, taking care of SQL injection.

Comment: So what does `list(qbe)` do? Please edit your question and include the code in the question. It's not very legible in the comments.

Comment: Sorry,I updated.Thank you

Comment: Well, at least you're getting a `parameterMap`. However that indicates named parameters (which is problematic if you want to use varargs), and you'd have to pass that to `findUniqueByQuery`, and then to `list()`.  Can you include the code for `findByQuery`?

Comment: Ah, it's not a `Map`, just a badly named variable. But since your `list()` takes varargs, you can just modify or overload the `findUniqueByQuery` method to accept varargs params as well, passing them on to `list()`. Right? Then you just need to make sure the parameter placeholders (`?`) are used in your query.

Comment: I have my doubts, my task is " DAOs need to be using the varargs super methods to properly encode SQL queries". So do I need to try to use varargs on Bidstage findBidstageByName() which is the first code I send.Thanks.

Comment: Then it sounds like there's already a method you can call like `super.findUniqueByQuery(qbe.toString(), varargs);`. Just fill in the placeholders in the query.

Comment: Yes,I understand what you refer.Thank you for your time.